# MYSQL query GROUP BY DESC

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with query. My database tabels:

**FIRST TABLE**

```
Notification
id |  Subject  | date_add
---+ ----------+---------
 1 | Subject1 | 2020-04-01 12:06:00
 2 |  Subject2 | 2020-04-18 19:12:59
 3 |  Subject3 | 2020-04-21 13:46:01
 4 |  Subject4 | 2020-04-20 13:46:01
```

**SECOND TABLE**

```
Notification_post
    id | user_id | notification_id | description | date_add as post_date
    ---+---------+--------+-------------+---------
     1 | 1        | 1      | Text 1      | 2020-04-19 12:06:00
     2 | 2        | 1      | Text 2      | 2020-04-20 19:12:59
     3 | 3        | 1      | Text 3      | 2020-04-21 19:44:36
     4 | 2        | 2      | Text 1      | 2020-04-21 19:48:24
     5 | 1        | 2      | Text 2      | 2020-04-21 19:55:00
```

For example like a Post and comments. I want newest comment in post.

**Expected Output:**

```
Notification_ID |User_id | Subject | description  | post_date
----------------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------
       1        |    3   |  Subject1 |    text 3  | 2020-04-21 19:44:36
       2        |    1   | Subject2  |   Text 2   |  2020-04-21 19:55:00
```

**My query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM notification n 
LEFT JOIN notification_post p ON p.notification_id=n.id 
GROUP BY p.notification_id 
ORDER BY p.date_add DESC
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Notification_ID |User_id | Subject | description  | post_date
 ----------------+--------+---------+--------------+-------------
       1             1     Subject1     Text 1        2020-04-19 12:06:00
       2             2     Subcject2    Text 1        2020-04-21 19:48:24
```

I tried with MAX(date_add) but don't work or I do it something wrong

Comment: Why should it show `Desc3` instead of `Desc1`? You haven't specified how to choose which row in the group to show.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to group by a column in a `LEFT JOIN` table. All the rows with no match will have `NULL` for that column, and they'll be grouped together.

Comment: Just giving an expected output doesn't really explain the logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: Do you want the latest row in each group?

Comment: This tabel it's only example data. For example like a Post and comments. I want newest comment in post.

Comment: You should say that in the question. The solution is at the linked question.

Comment: In my case doesn't work

Comment: Update the question and show what you tried to use from that question, and I'll reopen it to show how to fix it.